# Postgres - creating English_United States.1252 collation

Tags: windows, localization, internationalization, collation, postgresql-9.2

Postgres 9.2 on Windows 7, I'm trying to **create English_United States.1252 custom collation**:

```
user=# create database test template template0 ENCODING = 'utf8' LC_COLLATE = 'English_United States.1252' LC_CTYPE = 'English_United States.1252';
CREATE DATABASE
user=# \c test
test=# create collation english from "English_United States.1252";
ERROR:  collation "English_United States.1252" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist
```

And as you see, the following error is displayed:
**ERROR:  collation "English_United States.1252" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist**

What's the proper way to create English United States collation on Windows for utf8 db encoding?

Comment: My guess would be that the "1252` in the collation name refers to "Windows codepage 1252", which is a variant of ISO8859-1, an 8-bit fixed encoding. So adding that collation with a UTF-8 (Unicode) encoding would make no sense.

Comment: This statement appears to work for me (pg 9.2.4 on WinXP). Also [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html) says: _On Windows, however, UTF-8 encoding can be used with any locale_, which refutes the theory of UTF-8 incompatibility with the *.1252 locale.

Comment: @Daniel Vérité I'm using Postgres 9.2.2 on Windows 7

Comment: If windows had the equivalent of `locale -a` you could check if this `English_United States` locale is installed on your system. There's an [open question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152866) about this on S.O., it doesn't seem simple unless you can code a Win32 API call.

Comment: The use of the keyword FROM means that command is not trying to create a new collation, it's trying to copy one. To create a collation you may use: CREATE COLLATION "English_United States.1252" (LC_COLLATE='English_United States.1252', LC_CTYPE='English_United States.1252'); Unfortunately while this is creatable in Windows it doesn't use UTF-8.

Comment: (cont'd) Actually, it probably does use UTF-8, since at least in my system, an inspection of the record created in pg_collation for the new collation reveals collencoding = 6, while pg_encoding_to_char(6) returns 'UTF8'. I shall therefore promote this comment to an answer.