# Format date in full month name in Arabic locale

Tags: r, date, settings, arabic

To format dates in the  full month name format : [Month Name] [YEAR] I use:

```
format(Sys.Date(),"%B %Y")
```

Now , I would do the same thing but in arabic:

```
## save locals
loc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","Arabic")
format(Sys.Date(),"%B %Y")
## "????? 2015"          ## <----should have "جويلية 2015"
## restore locales
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME",loc)
```

Arabic months are not replaced by "????". I don't think it is a print/Unicode problem since arabic is displayed correctly in the console:

```
"مرحبا "
[1] "مرحبا "
```

Internally `strptime`  is called for formatting, from `?strptime`:

> Locale-specific conversions to and from character strings are used where **appropriate** and **available**

I think `strptime` don't have the right translation in arabic language. If this is true where can I contribute to fix this?

### edit

AS pointed in comments This seems like it could be a system/OS problem specific.
indeed , under **Ubuntu**  machine , installing language-pack-ar  and calling

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "ar_AE.utf8"); 
format(Sys.Date(),"%B %Y") 
[1] "يوليو 2015"
```

gives the right answer.

But under **Windows** , turning the locale to Arabic ( settings panel -> region..) and  calling the same code of the question don't resolve the problem.

Comment: Nitpick - in the last line of the code, shouldn't `op` be `loc` to reset the locale?

Comment: This seems like it could be a problem specific to your system/OS. I get a warning that "OS reports request to set locale to "Arabic" cannot be honored" when I try to run your `Sys.setlocale` command because that locale isn't available on my system.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I get a different result  "Ìæííå 2015" but not arabic..at least here I have some UNICODE charcaters better than ???.

Comment: I installed `language-pack-ar` on my Ubuntu machine and called `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "ar_AE.utf8"); format(Sys.Date(),"%B %Y")` and received `[1] "يوليو 2015"`

Comment: To [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603564/using-weekdays-with-any-locale-under-windows) you offered [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26604195/3710546). [Richie Cotton](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26609089/3710546),  suggested to _"set LC_CTYPE before LC_TIME, or it won't work"_. Did you try this trick?

Comment: @Pascal thank you ! I tried it and it works fine!

Answer (score 3):

This answer is closely inspired from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603564/using-weekdays-with-any-locale-under-windows/26604195#26604195). I just added a format argument to the function given by @RichieCotton

```
get_today_windows <- function(locale = NULL, fmt = "%B %Y")
{
  if(!is.null(locale))
  {
    lc_ctype <- Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")
    lc_time <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
    on.exit(Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", lc_ctype))
    on.exit(Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", lc_time), add = TRUE)
    Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", locale)
    Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", locale)
  }
  ## here I am changing 
  today <- format(Sys.Date(), format = fmt )
  current_codepage <- as.character(l10n_info()$codepage)
  iconv(today, from = current_codepage, to = "utf8")
}
```

Testing it with different Arabic languages, since there some difference between countries:

```
get_today_windows("Arabic_Qatar")
## [1] "يوليو 2015"

get_today_windows("Arabic_Tunisia")
## [1] "جوييه 2015"

get_today_windows("Arabic_Saudi Arabia.1256")
## [1] "يوليو 2015"
```